# How to use a css selector that refers to a element outside the shadow root

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

I need to style a component based on the class attached to the `<body>`.
The `logo-placeholder` is contained inside a shadow root.
The `body` is outside, of course.

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
.logo-placeholder {
  background: url(logo_LIGHT.png);
}

body.dark .logo-placeholder {
  background: url(logo_DARK.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⚠️ Disclaimer: *this solution has limited browser support as pointed out by @stephband in the comments, and it might be removed in the future. See more at [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=host-context). To understand the underlying reasons, have a look at these issues [github](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1914), [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1082060).*

---

**A complete solution would be as follows:**

```css
:host-context(body.dark) .logo-placeholder {
  background: url(logo_DARK.png);
}
```

`:host-context(body.dark)` means that the selector `body.dark` must be evaluated in the context of the host container, not based on the shadow-DOM. This is the reason it works.

---

Whenever we want a custom element to be styled based on its position in the DOM rather than obeying to the shadow-DOM rules, we can use the [`:host-context()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host-context).

> [`:host-context()`] allows a custom element, or anything within that custom element's shadow DOM, to apply different styles based on its position within the outer DOM or classes/attributes applied to ancestor elements.

> Another typical use would be to allow inner elements to react to classes or attributes on any ancestor elements - for example, applying a different text color when a `.dark-theme` class is applied to `<body>`.

Comment: Worth pointing out host-context is not implemented in Safari or FireFox: https://caniuse.com/?search=host-context

Answer (score 0):

A huge point with shadow dom that is self-contained. That goes with the CSS as well. Think of each component as a HTML document of its own.

If you want to style an element inside a placeholder, you need to do something like this.

```
<body>
  <custom-element class="dark-background"></custom-element>
</body>
```

Then inside the `custom-element`, style your div based on the [host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host)'s class.

```
:host(.dark-background) .logo-placeholder {
  background: url(logo_DARK.png);
}
```

---

Another way would be to use CSS properties.

```
body custom-element {
  --logo-placeholder-background: 'logo_LIGHT.png';
}

body.dark custom-element {
  --logo-placeholder-background: 'logo_DARK.png';
}
```

Then declare the following inside your `custom-element`

```
.logo-placeholder {
  --background-fallback: 'logo_LIGHT.png';

  background: url(var(--logo-placeholder-background, --background-fallback);
}
```

Comment: Sure, but that would be inconvenient. I want to set the body to `<body class="dark">` and I want the components to react to that. Also, using css variables means I need to set them outside the component, breaking compartmentalization even more.

Comment: I actually found a solution with `:host-context()`. I'll try to update your answer when stackoverflow let me do that.

Comment: Just make an answer of your own, and set that as the correct one, so people can link to this thread in the future. Good that everything worked out in the end. :)